# Does Groovy have extension methods like in C#?

Tags: groovy, extension-methods

Can I add to a method to a final class somehow like in C#?

So I could do something like:

```
"Some text".myOwnFunction();
```

Instead of:

```
MyStaticClass.myOwnFunction("Some text");
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can either add it to all future string instances via the metaClass

```
    String.metaClass.myOwnFunction = {-> delegate.length() }
    assert "Tim".myOwnFunction() == 3
```

Or you can add it to a single instance

```
    String a = "Tim"
    a.metaClass.myOwnFunction = {-> delegate.length() }
    assert a.myOwnFunction() == 3
```

Or you can add these methods when a jar is in the classpath at startup with [extension modules](http://mrhaki.blogspot.co.uk/2013/01/groovy-goodness-adding-extra-methods.html)

Comment: How to access the extended class?